# Conclusion from summands about the eigenvalues of a matrix sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, semidefinite-programming

Lets say I've given a sum of matrices
$$ \sum_{i\in[n]}A_i = A$$
where I know that all the $A_i$ are positive semidefinite.

Now given a single vector $v$, I'd like to know if I can make any statement in terms of the individual $A_i$ about the possible range of a scalar $t$ such that
$$ t\cdot A - vv^T$$
is positive semidefinite. Ideally, this would break down to some evaluations of the $A_i$ considered as quadratic and / or linear forms.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M \geq 0$ mean that $M$ is positive semidefinite.
Note that 
$$
tA - vv^T \geq 0 \iff\\
x^T(tA - vv^T)x \geq 0 \quad \forall x \iff\\
t(x^TAx) \geq (v^Tx)^2 \quad \forall x \iff\\
\frac{(x^TAx)}{(v^Tx)^2} \geq \frac 1t \quad \forall x
$$

---

Now, for a matrix $A_i$, we can define
$$
M_i = \max_{v^Tx \neq 0} \frac{(x^TA_ix)}{(v^Tx)^2}
$$
Then $t$ can only be such that $tA - vv^T \geq 0$ if
$$
\frac 1t \leq \sum_{i=1}^n M_i
$$
note that this condition is necessary, but not sufficient. Now, define
$$
m_i = \min_{v^Tx \neq 0} \frac{(x^TA_ix)}{(v^Tx)^2}
$$
Then $t$ will be such a value if
$$
\frac 1t \leq \sum_{i=1}^n m_i + \max_{i} (M_i - m_i)
$$
Note that this condition is sufficient, but not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I'm not quite sure if I can use it for my proof though, so I'd like to leave the question open for a bit longer, in case someone finds something different. I guess the min/max are intrinsic to this kind of problem, but if there was someone else, I'd be happy to know it.